# If string then paste the count value in an offset column and add one to count for next value

Tags: vba, for-loop, count, return-value, offset

hopefully this is an easy one. In this For loop, I would like VBA to read in the first range (LeftStrike) for the string "Foot Strike" and then assign the value of "1" and put that assigned value in the offset cell. Then I want it to add 1 to assigned value and run the For loop again, looking for the next "Foot Strike" string. That way, I can see what row the "First" foot strike is, and so on. I'm really struggling with understanding the .value of one thing = .value of another thing in order to "copy and paste" so to speak.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim LeftStrike As Range, FrameLTD As Range, StepNum As Range
Dim lrL As Long, LastFrame As Long
Dim StepCount As Long
StepCount = 1


lrL = ws.Range("H" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastFrame = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set LeftStrike = ws.Range("H2:H" & lrL)
Set StepNum = ws.Range("J2:J" & lrL)

For Each FrameLTD In LeftStrike
   If InStr(FrameLTD, "Foot Strike") Then
           ' assign value of "1" to StepCount
           ' somehow get StepCount to = FrameLTD.Offset(0, 3).Value
           ' StepCount = StepCount + 1

    End If
Next FrameLTD

MsgBox "Steps Numbered"
End Sub
```

Can someone tell me what my lines of code should be within the For Loop to get my "step count" into the offset column???

Comment: `FrameLTD.Offset(0, 3).Value = StepCount`

Comment: I edited the original question to include the whole code that I have.

Comment: If I use "FrameLTD.Offset(0, 3).Value = StepCount" it doesn't put any values in worksheet. It just says that it ran and shows the message box, but no "StepCount" values are in the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tim Williams solution should work!

- Double-check that you are looking/referring code to the correct worksheet (it will
  print values in "Sheet1")
- The values will be printed in column K as
  the range you refer to is column H and then you offset it by 3
  columns. You don't have any other code running that will overwrite this column?

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Dim LeftStrike As Range, FrameLTD As Range, StepNum As Range
Dim lrL As Long, LastFrame As Long
Dim StepCount As Long

StepCount = 1

lrL = ws.Range("H" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastFrame = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set LeftStrike = ws.Range("H2:H" & lrL)
Set StepNum = ws.Range("J2:J" & lrL)

For Each FrameLTD In LeftStrike
   If InStr(FrameLTD, "Foot Strike") Then
           'assign value of "1" to StepCount
           'somehow get StepCount to = FrameLTD.Offset(0, 3).Value
           FrameLTD.Offset(0, 3).Value = StepCount
           StepCount = StepCount + 1
    End If
Next FrameLTD

MsgBox "Steps Numbered"
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: You are right, it works! Thank you. The reason I thought it didn't work was because at some point earlier today, I had unknowingly  erased all the "Foot Strike" values in Column H, so the code was reading through, not finding any "Foot Strike" and then subsequently not numbering anything 3 columns over. Oops. Thanks again for your help!!!